# Not able to add Service Reference in VS2008

Tags: .net, visual-studio, service-reference

I'm working with an older project, .NET 3.5 with Visual Studio 2008, and I cannot add a service reference.  The error/details given aren't very helpful to me (posted below).  I am able to add this with newer projects in VS 2012.  What am I missing here?

Here are the details:

There was an error downloading 'https://site/service.wsdl'.
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://site/service.wsdl'.
An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://site/service.wsdl. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

Comment: oof; I hate to say it, but it is getting *really* hard to get support for VS2008 - frankly, it is a decade old, and the runtimes it targets are obsolete; the only thing I can suggest is : try the command-line tools directly (`svcutil`, etc)

Comment: Wow, thank you for that.  I just upgraded it to VS2012 to test and adding the service reference worked perfectly.  I'll do some more testing but I believe that's all I need - thanks!